# Rigging tank tracks

Tags: rigging

I am making a tank in Blender and now I am at the part where I need to create the wheels and track parts.

I want my tracks to have physics with the ground, so I guess I should rig the wheels. But I also want the tracks to smoothly follow the tracks and be affected by the ground and gravity.

My question is, how do I proceed with this?
Do I have to parents objects and stuff? I've got no idea on how to do this.

Creating the models is not the problem, but rigging it is.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: "I've got no idea on how to do this." This tells me you're looking for a tutorial.

"Do I have to parents objects and stuff?" This tells me you haven't put in the effort yourself. Both of those things are a big "no-no" on a StackExchange site.

If you have a question that is not specific to YOUR project, we'll be happy to answer it. 

I remember seeing a really cool track rig (without using a physics sim) on Blender Nation a while back. The information is available, it's just not here.

Comment: @Matt please don't be that harsh this site is still developing and shouldn't scare users away. Could you please add a link to the tutorial you mentioned?

Comment: I will be less harsh in the future. I agree and I hadn't intended to be harsh, just brief. I would add a link, but it was several years ago. My intent was to give the OP hope that the information is out there somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but you were right. I should be more constructive and I will be next time. In the meanwhile I'll keep searching for what I am looking for.

Comment: Would it be [this](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/05/30/model-download-tiger-tank-rig/)?